# Symfony2, Swiftmailer, Mandrill get response

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, mandrill

We've build an email system using Swiftmailer and Mandrill. It works really great but now we would like to integrate the webhooks to trigger alerts on bounces / failures / ...

At this moment we add a custom header with an unique id to each email sent and find our way back when the webhook triggers.

It works well but mandrill already uses an _id that we could use so that we do not add 'another' unique ID on top of that.

Mandrill responds with something like:

```
[
    {
        "email": "recipient.email@example.com",
        "status": "sent",
        "reject_reason": "hard-bounce",
        "_id": "abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123"
    }
]
```

Is there any way in Swiftmailer to get this response back into Symfony ?
(So that we can read and store that `_id` for later use)

I know we could use the Mandrill php SDK but preferably we would like to keep on using Swiftmailer.

**EDIT**
We are using SMTP Transport with a basic Swiftmailer instance as explained [here](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582157-How-to-Send-with-SwiftMailer)

```
<?php

include_once "swift_required.php";

$subject = 'Hello from Mandrill, PHP!';
$from = array('you@yourdomain.com' =>'Your Name');
$to = array(
 'recipient1@example.com'  => 'Recipient1 Name',
 'recipient2@example2.com' => 'Recipient2 Name'
);

$text = "Mandrill speaks plaintext";
$html = "<em>Mandrill speaks <strong>HTML</strong></em>";

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587);
$transport->setUsername('MANDRILL_USERNAME');
$transport->setPassword('MANDRILL_PASSWORD');
$swift = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = new Swift_Message($subject);
$message->setFrom($from);
$message->setBody($html, 'text/html');
$message->setTo($to);
$message->addPart($text, 'text/plain');

if ($recipients = $swift->send($message, $failures))
{
 echo 'Message successfully sent!';
} else {
 echo "There was an error:\n";
 print_r($failures);
}

?>
```

Comment: You should mention what you're using to send messages from swiftmailer using Mandrill, since the answer likely lies somewhere in that package.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Mandrill supports passing this reply via SMTP, you'll have to use API for that.

For example, in `accord/mandrill-swiftmailer` there is a method that returns response from Mandrill: https://github.com/AccordGroup/MandrillSwiftMailer/blob/master/SwiftMailer/MandrillTransport.php#L215

You can get Mandrill's response using following code:

```
$transport = new MandrillTransport($dispatcher);
$transport->setApiKey('ABCDEFG12345');
$transport->setAsync(true); # Optional
$response = $transport->getMandrillMessage($message);
// $response now contains array with Mandrill's response.
```

You can integrate it with Symfonu using [accord/mandrill-swiftmailer-bundle](https://github.com/AccordGroup/MandrillSwiftMailerBundle) and after that you can do:

```
$response = $mailer->getTransport()->getMandrillMessage($message);
```